# How to Rank based on more than 1 column? Partition by and Order by clauses

Tags: sql, rank, informatica-powercenter

How can I use the `SQL` rank function in Informatica Powercenter, on more than one column, when the Partition By clause has more than one column too?
As the below example shows:

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY  A,  B,  C,  D, E  
             ORDER BY F,  G,  H  )
```

I've have tried by `EXPRESSION` transformation, but as we need to concatenate to compare, it looses precision. And tried by `RANK` transformation, but it only accepts ranking by one column.

Is there any other way to lead with this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by on more than one column? Could what you want be accomplished by using two Rank() functions in the select clause?

Comment: Hi, I mean... we need to rank by columns F, G and H. In the RANK transformation in Powercenter, we can only rank by one of these columns, and if we concatenate these three columns to compare in the RANK transformation, as these columns became an string (due to the concatenation) we can't get the properly result. So, in the informatica powercenter, is there any way to lead with this situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked out with some sample Input, Hope this will help you..

Flow:

```
SQ --> Sorter --> Aggregator --> | --> Joiner --> Target
               |---------------> |
```

Input:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7|Col8
1|2|3|4|5|1|1|2
1|2|3|4|6|1|1|3
1|2|3|4|5|1|1|1
1|2|3|4|5|1|1|1
1|2|3|4|6|1|1|4
```

Output:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7|Col8|Rank
1|2|3|4|5|1|1|1|1
1|2|3|4|5|1|1|1|1
1|2|3|4|5|1|1|2|3
1|2|3|4|6|1|1|3|4
1|2|3|4|6|1|1|4|5
```

Mapping:

[image: Partition]